# How can I reuse mocha tests so I don't have to repeat myself?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm trying to write some tests in mocha that I'm going to automate in several browsers via BrowserStack. Rather than repeat the `test.it` code for each browser, I want to keep my code DRY and wrap a few `test.it` blocks in a function and just call that function inside of `test.describe`, like this (the actual test details are unimportant);

```
function runTests(driver) {
  test.it('form works', function() {
    var result = testForm(driver, '#formId', 'test@test.com');
    return 'Expected Result' === result;
  });
}

test.describe('Tests for IE 9', function() {
  var driver;

  test.before(function() {
    var capabilities = {
      'browser' : 'IE',
      'browser_version' : '9.0'
    };
    driver = setupDriver(capabilities);
  });

  runTests(driver);

  test.after(function() { driver.quit(); });
});

test.describe('Tests for IE 10', function() {
  var driver;

  test.before(function() {
    var capabilities = {
      'browser' : 'IE',
      'browser_version' : '10.0'
    };
    driver = setupDriver(capabilities);
  });

  runTests(driver);

  test.after(function() { driver.quit(); });
});
```

But since this code is async, `driver` is not defined when `runTests()` is called, so it fails. How can I structure this so that I don't have to repeat the `test.it` blocks for each browser?

Answer (score 1):

I would structure it like this:

```
function makeTests(kind, version) {
    describe("Tests for " + kind + " " + version, function () {
        var driver;
        before(function() {
            var capabilities = {
                'browser' : kind,
                'browser_version' : version
            };
            driver = setupDriver(capabilities);
        });

        it('form works', function() {
            var result = testForm(driver, '#formId', 'test@test.com');
            if ('Expected Result' !== result)
                throw new Error("failed!");
        });

        // Add more tests here...

        after(function() { driver.quit(); });
    });
}

makeTests('IE', '9');
makeTests('IE', '10');
```

I've used `describe` and `it` directly in the code above rather than `test.describe`, etc. I suppose your test environment wraps Mocha calls or that you are using an interface I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha also uses concept of injecting "done" callback for async tests. So if you specify this callback in "beforeEach", "it" and "afterEach", Mocha will inject it and don't execute next method until this callback is called. So I would change your code this way:

```
function runTests(driver, done) {
  test.it('form works', function(done) {
    var result = testForm(driver, '#formId', 'test@test.com');
    return 'Expected Result' === result;
    done();
  });
}

test.describe('Tests for IE 9', function() {
  var driver;

  test.before(function(done) {
    var capabilities = {
      'browser' : 'IE',
      'browser_version' : '9.0'
    };
    driver = setupDriver(capabilities);
    done();
  });

  runTests(driver, done);

  test.after(function(done) {
    driver.quit(); 
    done();
  });
});
```

You can find more information about [asynchronous testing with mocha here](https://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#asynchronous-code).